# File struct isn't viewed as implementing a Read?

Tags: rust, traits

I am making a trait which will read/decode to certain object from a variety of file formats. The trait has a generic `std::io::Read` class for the inner reader object. I'm trying to make a convenience `from_filename` constructor which will open the file and use that. However I cannot seem to make it work.

This is the code:

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::fs;
use std::path::Path;

trait MyObjectReader {
    type R: Read;

    fn new(Self::R) -> Self;

    fn from_filename(filename: &str) -> Self where Self: Sized {
        let open_file = fs::File::open(&Path::new(filename)).unwrap();
        Self::new(open_file)
    }

    // other methods will go here
}
```

And then I get this error:

```
rustc 1.15.1 (021bd294c 2017-02-08)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> <anon>:14:19
   |
14 |         Self::new(open_file)
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^ expected associated type, found struct `std::fs::File`
   |
   = note: expected type `<Self as MyObjectReader>::R`
   = note:    found type `std::fs::File`
```

*I know an `.unwrap()` is sub-par in a library, I'll change that later.*

I can't understand this error, because doesn't `std::fs::File` implement `std::io::Read`? To my mind it should work.

Comment: `File::open(&Path::new(filename))` is redundant; `File::open(filename)` suffices.

Answer (score 3):

> doesn't `std::fs::File` implement `std::io::Read`?

Yes. But consider an implementation of your trait:

```
impl MyObjectReader for SomeReaderImpl {
    type R = AnythingYouLike;
    // .. etc
}
```

The problem is that that `R` *could* be `File`, but it might not be.

Your default implementation is assuming that `R` is `File`, so perhaps that implementation should go in the specific instance where `R` is *definitely* `File`:

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::fs;

trait MyObjectReader {
    type R: Read;

    fn new(Self::R) -> Self;

    fn from_filename(filename: &str) -> Self where Self: Sized;
}

struct MyFileReader;

impl MyObjectReader for MyFileReader {
    type R = fs::File;

    fn new(_: Self::R) -> Self {
        MyFileReader
    }

    fn from_filename(filename: &str) -> Self
        where Self: Sized
    {
        let open_file = fs::File::open(filename).unwrap();
        Self::new(open_file)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is you can now only implement `MyObjectReader` for types where `MyObjectReader::R` is `File` (or can somehow come from a `File`), otherwise there's no way to implement the required `from_filename` method, unless you just `panic!` or something. Not really your fault; the problem statement is the cause.

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes. It would probably make more sense to move `from_filename` out of the trait, and make it a regular method of `MyFileReader`.

Answer (score 1):

Generic types aren't like interfaces. Bounds are not subclassing.

`type R: Read` does not mean *any* type that implements `Read`. It's not an abstract class. It's more like a placeholder/alias. It means *one specific* type that implements `Read`. And which type it is going to be is defined only in the `impl` block, so the `trait` block doesn't know it at that point.

Another way to look at it is that by saying `from_filename` returns `Self` (with arbitrary `R: Read`), it has to work for *every* implementation of `Read`, but your implementation can only return `Self<R=File>`.

Answer (score 0):

You may also wish to move the location of your generic to the `new` method:

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::fs::File;

trait MyObjectReader {
    fn new<R: Read>(R) -> Self;

    fn from_filename(filename: &str) -> Self
        where Self: Sized
    {
        let open_file = File::open(&filename).unwrap();
        Self::new(open_file)
    }
}
```

This says that `new` can take *any* type that implements `Read`, regardless of how the implementation of the trait defines `R`. This can be combined with an associated type if you still need that for other methods that aren't currently shown:

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::fs::File;

trait MyObjectReader {
    type R: Read;

    fn new<R2: Read>(R2) -> Self;

    fn from_filename(filename: &str) -> Self
        where Self: Sized
    {
        let open_file = File::open(&filename).unwrap();
        Self::new(open_file)
    }

    fn something_else(&self) -> Self::R;
}
```